# Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 for ubuntu-based OS like Lubuntu, Bodhi Linux

Tags: drivers, lubuntu

I find that Netflix flickers with the video driver that comes with the Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installation. Same thing with Bodhi Linux. The streaming quality is not as good as when using the driver that comes with Windows 10. This is unfortunate and one of the things preventing me from leaving Windows.

There seems to be no proprietary driver. Any suggestions? My internet connection is fine in all systems.

Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000

Comment: Indeed there are no proprietary drivers because Intel graphics drivers are open-source. Your graphics is too old and Intel dropped support for it a long time ago. It barely works in Windows 10 with a very old driver and sooner than later it'll also not work properly in Windows. In any Linux distro, forget it.

Comment: If it craps out in Windows 10 would going back to Windows 7 be a viable solution (on a PC with no sensitive info, of course...)?

Comment: There's no reason for using an outdated out of support OS. Those are the ones used to hack others, perform denial of service attacks etc.etc. It's not your data I'm worried about but everyone else's. That said this a Ubuntu dedicated website. Anything Windows other than dual-booting with Ubuntu is obviously off-topic.

Comment: Lubuntu is a *flavor* of Ubuntu, uses the same code and repositories as Ubuntu and is not *ubuntu-based* but a legitimate form of Ubuntu (we communicate in the same rooms etc; I'm both a Lubuntu & Ubuntu member).  Yes Bodhi Linux is Ubuntu-based, but that's off-topic here as it's not Ubuntu nor *flavor* of Ubuntu, and doesn't belong.  Lubuntu only has a different desktop (and thus programs/toolkits) to Ubuntu's default of GNOME - that's what a *flavor* is; it's the same system/software though.

Comment: Of note: Lubuntu media comes with **no** 3rd party of proprietary drivers unlike main Ubuntu and other *flavors*, those are optionally added to your system by the user (we aim at being *light* and drivers increase the size of the ISO significantly)

Answer (score 2):

My old Thinkpad T410 still runs flawlessly (with Netflix). Intel graphics does not need a proprietary driver, but I'd check if Lubuntu has the XCompmgr (the xfwm compositor) activated. The xfwm compositor handles vsync really badly.

To check, execute:

`inxi -Gxx | grep compositor`

in a terminal.

If it is the XCompmgr, try compton or compiz on Lubuntu.

Comment: Currently am single-booted into Windows. When I get a chance I will dual boot, test, and probably ask for more info.

Comment: You can't watch Netflix on a live USB stick. (Only basic drivers are installed in RAM) That information was missing. But HD 3000 is very well supported by Linux and is **not** considered as "old" - I'm running Netflix also on a Raspi 2 (reduced resolution) which definitely has not the horsepower of your laptop.

Comment: @kanehekili HD3000 **is** old and already unsupported by Intel. I've tested one of those years ago and couldn't get Youtube higher than 480P!! With Windows 10 it barely worked at 1080P (50/60 frames, forget it). According to Lenovo, a Thinkpad T410 has a newer a much more powerful Intel Core i5-520M. An ARM based device isn't comparable, even the original RPi could (and still can) play/stream videos at 1080P easily.

Comment: I can get 1080p: 1920x1080 with that driver sent thru our HDMI TV... and thru my external VGA monitor...

Comment: I ask questions to learn. As for Windows talk being inappropriate, I understand and thank all for the helpful info. However, I asked because if Windows 7 would not work, I would try harder to find a way to make Ubuntu work. So in that sense, it was relevant. It was an indirect Ubuntu question.

Comment: *I can get 1080p: 1920x1080 with that driver sent thru our HDMI TV* So did I as in the desktop resolution. Now try Youtube. You already know what happens with Netflix. Windows 10 is what gives the best results. Window 7 is the same at best and EoL OSes shouldn't be used, period. Especially when there absolutely nothing to gain from using it instead of a supported and current OS. There's nothing you can do to improve Ubuntu on that old hardware or Windows 10 for that matter, it is what it is. The hardware has been relegated to legacy status a long time ago so consider replacing it.

Comment: There's no point in beating a dead horse, you're just wasting your and others' time.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I still not concur. Thats one of the things linux is for: Keeping older hardware alive. And for me HD3000 is **new**, since my hardware is even older. And asking questions is *NO* waste of time